# FlatList re-rendering every time i type something in TextInput

Tags: javascript, performance, react-native

I don't think this is a bug, more like I'm doing something wrong but here it goes.
I'm building a Chat Component for my application, it's very simple, I type something press send button adds to the list and displays.
Days ago I found that if I started typing big and quick messages my JS FPS would drop to like 10, 5 even 1 and I found out today thanks to implementing a data/time display for the messages that each time I type something in the TextInput and run onChangeText event and change the state of "text" it re-renders ALL the items inside my FlatList

Here is my code:

Chat Component:

```
<FlatList
    key={'chat'}
    ref={(ref) => {flatlistRef = ref}}
    style={styles.flatlist_main}
    data={this.state.items}
    extraData={this.state}
    renderItem={this.renderItem}
    keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}
    onContentSizeChange={(contentWidth, contentHeight) => {
          flatlistRef.scrollToEnd({animated: true});
    }}
    onLayout={() => {flatlistRef.scrollToEnd({animated: true})}}
/>
```

onChangedText Function

```
onFooterTextChanged = (text) => {
    this.setState({
        text: text,
        options_expanded: false,
    });
};
```

onSendMessage Button Function

```
onSendButtonPressed = () => {
    if(this.state.text !== null && this.state.text !== "") {
        this.setState({
            items: [
                ...this.state.items,
                {
                    id: moment().valueOf(),
                    text: this.state.text,
                    date: moment().valueOf(),
                    user: {
                        id: globals.user_id_value,
                        avatar: globals.user_photo,
                    }
                }
            ],
            text: "",
            options_expanded: true,
        });
    }
};
```

renderItem Function for FlatList

```
renderItem = (item) => {
    const data = item.item;
    const renderAvatar = this.renderAvatar(item);
    const renderTime = this.renderTime(item);
    if('text' in data){
        return(
            <ChatTextItem
                keyy={data.id}
                self={globals.user_id_value === data.user.id}
                text={data.text}
                user={data.user}
                renderAvatar={renderAvatar}
                sameUser={!renderAvatar}
                renderTime={renderTime}
                time={this.getTime(data.date)}
            />
        )
    } else if('image' in data) {
        return(
            <ChatImageItem
                keyy={data.id}
                self={globals.user_id_value === data.user.id}
                image={data.image}
                renderAvatar={renderAvatar}
                sameUser={!renderAvatar}
                renderTime={renderTime}
                time={this.getTime(data.date)}
            />
        )
    }
};
```

Constructor if it helps

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        isLoading: false,
        options_expanded: true,
        text: "",
        image: "",
        items: [],
    };
}
```

and I'm user PureComponent btw.

Edit #1: Console after typing like a madman in the TextInput
[image]
It re-rendered 28 times for the 28 letters I typed and it does that * the number of items in the list already

Edit #2: Changes Made to the JS file

Changed FlatList extraData option

```
 <FlatList
      key={'chat'}
      ref={(ref) => {flatlistRef = ref}}
      style={styles.flatlist_main}
      data={this.state.items}
      extraData={this.state.refresh}
      renderItem={this.renderItem}
      keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}
      onContentSizeChange={(contentWidth, contentHeight) => {
            flatlistRef.scrollToEnd({animated: true});
      }}
      onLayout={() => {flatlistRef.scrollToEnd({animated: true})}}
  />
```

and changed the constructor to add refresh state

```
 constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        isLoading: false,
        options_expanded: true,
        text: "",
        image: "",
        items: [],
        refresh: false,
    };
}
```

Issue still persists

Edit: #3 Finally found the issue

**Works**

```
<FlatList
                key={'chat'}
                ref={(ref) => {flatlistRef = ref}}
                style={styles.flatlist_main}
                data={this.state.items}
                extraData={this.state.refresh}
                renderItem={this.renderItem}
                keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}

            />
```

**Doesn't Work**

```
 <FlatList
                key={'chat'}
                ref={(ref) => {flatlistRef = ref}}
                style={styles.flatlist_main}
                data={this.state.items}
                extraData={this.state.refresh}
                renderItem={this.renderItem}
                keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}
                onContentSizeChange={(contentWidth, contentHeight) => {
                    flatlistRef.scrollToEnd({animated: true});
                }}
                onLayout={() => {flatlistRef.scrollToEnd({animated: true})}}
            />
```

Any Ideas Why? Please!

If someone could help me find a solution to my problem I would appreciate it.

Comment: in `FlatList` you re-render whenever `this.state` changes with `extraData={this.state}` and `onTextChange` you update `this.state`. That's why it's always re-render `FlatList` too.

Comment: I removed `extraData={this.state}` but continues to re-render everytime i type something

Comment: You should not remove `extraData` because if you remove it. The `FlatList` USUALLY won't re-render anymore. Do something like @soutot shows you on his answer. BTW, when you remove `extraData` and it's still re-rendering. It means you are not running newest code or something totally wrong there.

Comment: if you check again the post I updated it with the changes I made and the issue still persists, do you have any idea if its cache related?
Thanks for your answer

Comment: With information you have provided. I don't see anything wrong there.

Comment: I'm going to try and see how I can clean the cache and clean the build and il be back update the status of the situation thank you for your time

Comment: I ran **gradlew cleanBuildCache** in the **/android** folder and the issue persists, my extraData Prop keeps fetching for the `this.state` instead of the `this.state.refresh` that I provided and I know this because I tested with other state values and any value I change it re-renders the list
Any ideas or other commands to clear cache or other things that might be causing this issue?
Thanks in advance

Comment: uninstall the app and run `react-native run-android` again :) ( there is other ways but this is far easiest one )

Comment: I found out whats causing it, apparently, if I remove `onContentSizeChanged` and `onLayout` he stops re-rendering when I type, why is that?

Comment: I can't find anything relate to them on `FlatList` docs from `react-native`. But gratz that's you found the cause.

Comment: Thanks for your time, appreciate it, I guess I should open this issue in their GitHub page

Answer (score 3):

It looks like it's due to your `extraData` receiving the whole state

> This is a PureComponent which means that it will not re-render if
>   props remain shallow- equal. Make sure that everything your renderItem
>   function depends on is passed as a prop (e.g. extraData) that is not
>   === after updates, otherwise your UI may not update on changes. This includes the data prop and parent component state

So this is the expected behavior since you are updating your state every time the user types in your input field.

Also, FlatList should render (or rerender) only the items visible in the screen

> In order to constrain memory and enable smooth scrolling, content is
>   rendered asynchronously offscreen. This means it's possible to scroll
>   faster than the fill rate and momentarily see blank content. This is a
>   tradeoff that can be adjusted to suit the needs of each application,
>   and we are working on improving it behind the scenes.

Try fixing your `extraData`. Something like `extraData={this.state.refresh}` where `this.state.refresh` is updated when the user presses `send` button.

More details here: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the response, I changed Flatlist to have `extraData={this.state.refresh}` and in constructor `refresh: false` and never change it but it remains to re-render everytime I type and debugging it gives me the image I posted above in Edit #1.

Comment: You have some render methods inside your renderItem. Any of them consumes your state? Btw, theres a typo on ```key``` prop of yout chat text item component

Comment: First, to answer your question, I don't use setState in any of the items, and secondly, I provided my `extraData` Prop with `this.state.refresh` and ran on the */android* folder *gradlew cleanBuildCache* but for some reason the extraData Prop keep grabbing `this.state` and not `this.state.refresh`
Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I found out whats causing it, apparently, if I remove `onContentSizeChanged` and `onLayout` he stops re-rendering when I type, why is that?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, if I remove `onLayout` and `onContentSizeChanged` events from my `FlatList` it stops rendering on any state changes and only the state provided in extraData, still doesn't solve my issue and it only made performance worse surprisingly.
Thanks to everyone that helped to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

@Guy hope you have found solution.

But for new devs.
As per my struggle in same situation i found that:-
For any use case when Flatlist and TextInput in same component then please try to use Flatlist in separate component (PureComponent) and textInput in separate component.
Re-rendering will not happen.

Or you can use separate component for flatlist only, it will not re-render each time when state change.

Answer (score 0):

It is due to the hooks of text input present in the same component containing flatlist.

Separate whole text input from the component

```
//Component contains flat list
const ParentComponent = ()=>{
    return(
      <FlatList/>
      <CustomTextInput/>
    );
}

//Textinput separate component
const CustomTextInput = ()=>{
  const [value,setValue] = useState(null);

  return (
    <TextInput 
       value = {value} 
       onChangeText={(data)=>{setValue(data);}}
    />
  );

}
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't think it is bug, This is what we need it to your chat application right. As you were updating the state for each onPress(onSendButtonPressed) to show the new message in the list. So it re-renders the list. May be what i suggest is, you just show the recent messages in your flatlist. ie last 3 or 4 days message in the flatList and load more when the user goes backward beyond 4 days. This will help you to improve the performance of your chat application.

Comment: What I mean is, my FlatList is re-rendering each time I type something in TextInput, if the problem was only re-rendering when I press send would be fine but it re-rendered every time and run onTextChanged to update the "Text" State